# Getting value percentage in a mongo aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Below is the output after applying a mongo aggregation query.

```
[
  {
    _id: { category: 'electronics' },
    'sku count': 1087,
    'annual cost': 216035.68,
    'annual mrp': 287082.21,
    'margin %': 0.24747799593712197
  },
  {
    _id: { category: 'food' },
    'sku count': 5,
    'annual cost': 1063.3799999999999,
    'annual mrp': 1764.32,
    'margin %': 0.39728620658383973
  },
  {
    _id: { category: 'clothing' },
    'sku count': 363,
    'annual cost': 103426.6981633,
    'annual mrp': 143030.03,
    'margin %': 0.27688822995212964
  },
  {
    _id: { category: 'furniture' },
    'sku count': 1,
    'annual cost': 2407.41,
    'annual mrp': 3199,
    'margin %': 0.24744920287589878
  }
]
```

I want to calculate the value of each category of a store by `annual cost of a category/summation of annual cost across categories`. For example, to calculate the `value percentage of furniture` we have to apply the following forumla. `2407.41/(2407.41 + 103426.6981633 + 1063.3799999999999 + 216035.68)`.

I have written the below query to get the above result.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            store_name: "jasperstore"
        }
    },

    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                category: "$category",
            },
            "total_sku": {
                "$addToSet": "$sku"
            },
            "annual_cost": {
                $sum: "$rate_gst"
            },
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            },
            "total_mrp": {
                $sum: "$mrp"
            },
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            },
            total_margin_half: {
                $sum: { 
                    $subtract: [
                        {
                            $sum: "$mrp"
                        },
                        {
                            $sum: "$rate_gst"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {
            "sku count": {
                "$size": "$total_sku"
            },
            "annual cost": "$annual_cost",
            "annual mrp": "$total_mrp",
            "margin %": {
                $divide: [ "$total_margin_half", "$total_mrp" ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

I am trying to wrap my head around to fit the `value percentage` formula in this aggregation query. Any help would be great.

Cheers!

Comment: You can use `$group` to get the annual costs of each category into an array. Then `$unwind` to use the values from the array to calculate your value percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$facet` to categorize the incoming documents

- `$facet` to categorize the incoming documents, which helps to calculate the total
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$multiply` and `$divide` help to calculate the percentage

Here is the code

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "category": [
        { $match: { "_id.category": "furniture" } }
      ],
      total: [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": { "$sum": "$annual cost" }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$category" },
  { $unwind: "$total" },
  {
    $project: {
      percentage: {
        "$multiply": [
          { "$divide": [ "$category.annual cost", "$total.count" ] },
          100
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working Mongo [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bt3hYE3JvAh)**

Comment: hi…can i include it in the query (mentioned in the question)?

Comment: You can, but your query  seems wrong, you have multiple `count` in group which cannot be possible.

Comment: can there be multiple groups? and can variables be passed from one group to another?

Comment: There can my multiple group stages, and a key should be unique inside one group. I just need to know, you got the above documents after which aggregations? and what do you try to achieve using the above posted aggregation?

Comment: It is for BI purpose where i want to compute total sku count in each category, total mrp of items, total annual cost, margin % and value share which is described in the question.

Comment: @CK5 does the answer help you?